# Combine rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

I have data in column 1 and data in column 2 as follows:

```
1234      eggs
1234      bacon
1234      toast
4321      Orange Juice
```

I want it to appear as follows:

```
1234      eggs-bacon-toast
4321      orange juice
```

I would also like it to automatically delete the duplicate rows so that I have unique numbers in column 1 with just the combined data.

Comment: You'll need VBA. What have you tried already?

Comment: No I have never used Visual Basic is it hard?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a program or script to join the lines with the common key (column 1).

If you don't know VBA, then you can use a simple ruby script to do the join on the data from a CSV export of the worksheet.

Follow these steps:

1. Export your worksheet in CSV format.
2. Then run the script below on the data, producing a new,
   CSV-formatted output file.
3. Import the CSV-output file into Excel.

The data should look something like this:

```
$ cat joiner-data.csv
Key,Data
"1234",eggs
"1234",bacon
"1234",toast
"4321","Orange Juice"
```

Below is the ruby script to join the data by the column 1 key.

*By the way, this code doesn't care if the key data is numeric or not -- it will join data based on any key value.*

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# joiner.rb input >output
# read CSV data, with key in column one
# output each key once, with all associated data joined by '-'

require 'csv'

records = {}

input = ARGV.shift

CSV.foreach(input, :headers => true, :return_headers => false) do |row|
  data = row.fields
  key = data.shift
  records[key] ||= []       # ensure new keys start with an empty array
  records[key] += [data]    # append the record data
end

# output the record keys in ascending order, with the data associated with each key
CSV { |csv| records.keys.sort.each{|k| csv << [k,records[k].join('-')]}}

exit
```

Here's the sample run, using the above CSV-formatted data:

```
$ ./joiner.rb joiner-data.csv
1234,eggs-bacon-toast
4321,Orange Juice
```

This output should be put into a file that can be imported back into Excel.  Like this:

```
$ ./joiner.rb joiner-data.csv >joined-data.csv
```

Now import the file `joined-data.csv`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using vba is probably the most appropriate solution for this problem, but if you haven't used a programming language before, you might run into a few errors and not know what to do. The same goes for the solution aks gives, and that solution also requires exiting excel. That being said, its good to know how to manipulate csv files outside of excel, and you should be able to get what you want if you follow the steps aks gives.

If you just want a plug-in-play solution, I made a spreadsheet with all some formulas for you [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0oN8NMFAt6OQ2M2OEthcGNvV3M/preview?pli=1). To use it, paste your data into column A and B under the labels, pull down the formulas in C2-F2, then filter column F by non-blanks. The results will be in "FINAL A" and "FINAL B".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this isn't very difficult. First things first, [show the developer tab](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/show-the-developer-tab-or-run-in-developer-mode-HA010173052.aspx) by clicking the office button, going to Excel Options and selecting *show developer tab*. This allows you to edit and run macros.

On the ribbon, you have a developer tab now. Click that and go to the "visual basic". Now, up top in the VBA editor, click *insert - module*. In the module paste the code below:

```
Sub Macro1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'sort columns
    Columns("A:B").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B150440")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Dim c As Range
Dim strValue As String

'only non-blank cells
For Each c In Range("A:A")
    If c <> "" Then
Again:
        'check for matches and combine
        If c.Value = c.Offset(1).Value Then
           strValue = c.Offset(, 1).Value & "-" & c.Offset(1, 1).Value
           c.Offset(, 1) = strValue
           c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
           GoTo Again
        End If
    End If
Next c


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Run it and you'll be good to go.

**I would recommend making a copy of your data before running the macro and run the macro on the copy, in case it doesn't do what you want**